# How to extract value of all the child nodes of a specific node (provided through input parameter) from XMLType Column in Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

One of our requirements is to get the value of all the child nodes of a given specific XML node.
I have got a solution for this using Microsoft SQL Server but I need the same in Oracle. Please see the below query.

Note: incase if there is more than one child node, the result should be the concatenation of all the individual child nodes'value.

```
select 
REPLACE(Properties, 'utf-8', 'utf-16'),
CAST(REPLACE(Col1, 'utf-8', 'utf-16') as XML).value('(//*[local-name() = sql:variable("@var2")])[1]', 'varchar(200)')

from A
```

Following is a sample data/row from Col1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ConstantInputProperties xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Value xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Value></ConstantInputProperties>
```

here A is the table and Col1 is one of the columns of table A.

I tried to convert below Solution but it gives me the XML instead of values.

```
SELECT col1, 
EXTRACT(XMLTYPE(col1), '(/*[local-name()="ConstantInputProperties"][1])')
FROM A
```

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ConstantInputProperties xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Value xsi:type="ArrayOfInt"><int>0</int><int>1</int></Value></ConstantInputProperties> 

Expected Output 01

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ConstantInputProperties xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Value xsi:type="ArrayOfBoolean"><boolean>true</boolean><boolean>true</boolean><boolean>true</boolean><boolean>true</boolean><boolean>true</boolean></Value></ConstantInputProperties>

Expected Output truetruetruetruetrue


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ConstantInputProperties xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Value xsi:type="ArrayOfDecimal"><decimal>1.0000000000</decimal></Value></ConstantInputProperties>

Expected Output 1.0000000000
```

Comment: Show us a couple of examples please what exactly you need to get

Comment: Data: 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ConstantInputProperties xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Value xsi:type="ArrayOfInt"><int>0</int><int>1</int></Value></ConstantInputProperties>



Query in MS SQL

select col1,CAST(REPLACE(col1, 'utf-8', 'utf-16') as XML),
CAST(REPLACE(col1, 'utf-8', 'utf-16') as XML).value('(*[local-name()=sql:variable("@var")])[1]','nvarchar(200)')
from A





Output
01

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63230739/edit) to add information, particularly code that needs to be formatted to be readable. Can you really have `Value` as either Int or ArrayOfInt?

Comment: Yes, It can be both. And Result will be a string and all the values will be concatenated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could manipulate the XML inside an XPath with FLWOR syntax, but you could also use XMLTable to extract all the values; or rather, two XMLTables, one for a singleton element type and a second optional one for array expansion; get all the values as strings; and aggregate the results together:

```
select a.id,
  listagg(coalesce(x1.value, x2.value), ' ')
    within group (order by coalesce(x1.n, x2.n)) as result
from a
cross apply xmltable (
  '(/*[local-name()=$var1][1])'
  passing xmltype(col1), 'ConstantInputProperties' as "var1"
  columns
    n for ordinality,
    value varchar2(30) path 'Value[@xsi:type="xsd:int"]',
    array xmltype path 'Value[fn:starts-with(@xsi:type, "ArrayOf")]'
) x1
outer apply xmltable (
  'Value/*'
  passing array
  columns
    n for ordinality,
    value varchar2(30) path '.'
) x2
group by a.id;

ID | RESULT                  
-: | :-----------------------
 1 | 0                       
 2 | 0 1                     
 3 | true true true true true
 4 | 1.0000000000
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=917d5f46cdbd9cddad7373769b5f2595)

The `n for ordinality` just gives a numeric value that lets you keep the original sub-element order when aggregating (so you get `0 1` and not `1 0`), If you don't want a spaces added to to the aggregated value then just change the second `listagg` argument from `' '` to `null`, though then you can't sell the difference between a singleton 10 and a pair of values with 1 and 0, so that doesn't seem very useful - not that an aggregated value seems that useful anyway really.

You could split into multiple sub-XMLTables, but that's probably not going to gain you anything here; [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1c73f03f816a2dcf2af60d9b1907b48a) for info though.

---

> can you suggest how to pass the ConstantInputProperties value as an argument and use it as a variable in function input in this case EXTRACT(XMLTYPE(col1), '(/*[local-name()="ConstantInputProperties"]/*/text())')

The `extract()` function is deprecated. Use XMLQuery instead; for example:

```
select xmlquery(
  '(/*[local-name()=$var1][1])/Value/text()'
  passing xmltype(col1), 'ConstantInputProperties' as "var1"
  returning content)
from a
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you for your response. One thing I am stuck is with this one '//*[local-name()="ConstantInputProperties"]/*/text()'. Can you suggest a way to pass the ConstantInputProperties value as an argument and use it as a variable in function input

Comment: @SudarshanKeshri - my answer is already doing that, with `(/*[local-name()=$var1][1])'` and a second `passing` element, `'ConstantInputProperties' as "var1"`? Using `..../*/text()` works for your single `xsd:int` value but not for the arrays though, I think?

Comment: Yes.. But I am not able to use your approach inside a function.. I am getting this error
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qkebCreateColInFro:1], [], [], [],
[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [] . I found an alternate slution but could not able to pass the value as an argument and use it as a variable in the function input

Comment: Well, you can use the same `var1` bits with Sayan's answer, I just don't see how that addresses all your requirements, unless your modification is to use a union perhaps. ORA-600 is an internal error, you might find an answer to that through Oracle Support.

Comment: Yes. It didn't completely solve my requirement but it helped in moving forward. And for now, can't reach out to Oracle Support. One more thing, can you suggest how to  pass the ConstantInputProperties value as an argument and use it as a variable in function input in this case EXTRACT(XMLTYPE(col1), '(/*[local-name()="ConstantInputProperties"]/*/text())'). I tried the way you used in your solution, but it didn't work here

Comment: The extract function has been deprecated for a long time. Use XMLQuery instead. There's an example in an earlier [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ae94c4ac2381911d422973ce71085f12). Added that to my answer for info.

Answer (score 0):

Few examples:

```sql
with a as (
select q'[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ConstantInputProperties xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Value xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Value></ConstantInputProperties>  
]' col1 from dual
)
select
   x.*
from 
    a,
    xmltable(
        '//*[local-name()="ConstantInputProperties"][1]' 
        passing xmltype(a.col1)
        columns 
            res xmltype path '.'
) x;

--Result:
RES
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<ConstantInputProperties xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Value xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Value></ConstantInputProperties>
```

```sql
with a as (
select q'[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ConstantInputProperties xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Value xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Value></ConstantInputProperties>  
]' col1 from dual
)
select
   x.*
from 
    a,
    xmltable(
        '//*[local-name()="ConstantInputProperties"]/*/text()' 
        passing xmltype(a.col1)
        columns 
            res xmltype path '.'
) x;

--Result:
RES
--------------------------------------------------------------
<Value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:int">0</Value>
```

Comment: Hi Sayan, Thanks for your response but I need to extract the values of child nodes. 
In this example, the result should be 0.

Another Example:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ConstantInputProperties xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Value xsi:type="ArrayOfInt"><int>0</int><int>1</int></Value></ConstantInputProperties>

here result will be 01

Comment: @SudarshanKeshri I've updated second query, please check it out

Comment: Hi Sayan, Thank you for your response. I modified your query a bit to make it work for me. One thing I am stuck is with  this one '//*[local-name()="ConstantInputProperties"]/*/text()'. Can we pass the ConstantInputProperties value as an argument and use it as a variable in function input